# LongListSelector stopped scrolled and freezes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a `LongListSelector` (in `PivotItem`) control in Windows Phone 8 app. I see a strange behavior. Sometime the LLS stopped scrolled. Like freezes, I can't to scroll it. But I can use `AppBar`, `Pivot`, `Button Back`, etc. And even GroupHeader and JumpList. It happened randomly (so far I not found regularities) and quite often. Earlier I often used a LLS, but these problems have never been.

Following is a typical scenario when the LLS can freeze.

1. Go to page with the LLS.
2. Scrolled the LLS.
3. Tap the LLS item and navigated to other page.
4. Back to page with the LLS.
5. The LLS not scrolled.

This bag can occur in other ways too.

**Highlights:**

- I don't binding big collection to the LLS  (my collection about 10 - 50 items (in 5 groups)).
- When the LLS not frozen, then it's work very fast and without jerks.
- I have a `ListBox` (1 - 6 string elements) in the LLS items.
- I use DataTemplateSelector ([as implemented here)](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector).
- Profiling does not show poor responsiveness when the LLS frozen.

My XAML:

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Name="LLSSimpleSearch"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ListGroup}"
                         toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                         Margin="12,0,-12,0"                                                                   
                         IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
                         LayoutMode="List"
                         HideEmptyGroups="False"      
                         GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource LLSHeaderTemplate}"
                         JumpListStyle="{StaticResource LLSJumpList}"
                         ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource LLSListFooter}">
```

ItemTemplate

```
<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>
           <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox></ListBox> <!-- ListBox with small collect-->
           </DataTemplate>
<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>

<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template2>
           <DataTemplate>
           </DataTemplate>
</questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template2>

<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template3>
           <DataTemplate>
           </DataTemplate>
</questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template3>

<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template4>
           <DataTemplate>
           </DataTemplate>
</questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template4>
</questionary:QuestTemplateSelector>
```

In cs:

```
LLSSimpleSearch.DataContext = GYSearchViewModel.Instance;
GYSearchViewModel.Instance.Load();
```

ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Group<Quest>> _listGroup = new ObservableCollection<Group<Quest>>();
public ObservableCollection<Group<Quest>> ListGroup
        {
            get
            {
                return _listGroup;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _listGroup)
                {
                    _listGroup = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ListGroup");
                }
            }
        }

public Load()
{
     MyDataSource.Load((r) => { ListGroup= r; })
}
```

Something strange here? In this code, there are potential problems? I am ready to give more comments if it will need. Thanks for the advices in advance.

**UPDATE (solution of the problem)**

I can not be 100 percent sure, but 99 percent that the problem in the `ListBox`.

```
<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
               </DataTemplate>
<questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>
```

I must, show my data in list, and I use `ListBox` inside `LLS`. Experimental way, after a long testing I found regularity of freezes. Then come to the conclusion that the problem  in the `ListBox`. In the issue property `IsHitTestVisible` helped.

```
 <questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>
                   <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
    <questionary:QuestTemplateSelector.Template1>
```

Now no problems.

Answer (score 3):

The more controls (or items) which the phone has to render will cause a slowdown in relation to the total number of items shown. On a WP8 window I was working on, 50+ items to be rendered would slow the app down noticeably to the point where I had to redesign how these things were loaded and displayed.

Either its a load latency issue, or a display issue or both. You need to determine the bottleneck(s) and decide what trade-offs will make the operation fast regardless.

Try loading the controls with static data (already pre-loaded on the phone app) to see if its the load, or the loading of the screen such as a divide an conquer type of profiling.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, tomorrow I will try bind static data to the LLS and remove ListBox from Items. I'll tell about the results in post update.

Comment: OmegaMan, I'm updated my post, think I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what I'm saying is right - but just for the sake of it

Do you fetch items from the internet and add them to observable collection to which the longlistselector is binded?? do you use "await" keyword?? maybe some heavy processing in the OnNavigatedTo() method?

If so, it could be possible that the process of fetching the stuff from internet runs in the UI thread and not in another thread or some other task that should not happen in the foreground is blocking the CPU - this means that the app is waiting to process the data and the CPU is blocked until all data is fetched from the net - during this time the app will be unresponsive - you can use scroll the pivot, use appbar etc. but I think those would be limited to just the UI behaviour - they would not function